# Значение Default на тип int в mysql

Tags: mysql

Дайте мне совет пожалуйста. 
У меня есть поля значение, тип которого целое число. Я хочу дать значение на `Default=000000`. Но значение он не берет. Я хочу чтоб каждое регистрированный число сохранялось с нулями в поле. Например: пользователь вводить - 111111, в поле записывается 111111. А если пользователь вводить - 3425, в поле должно запысивается - 003425.
Или лучше этого контролировать на сервере???

Comment: если вам нужно показывать число с ведущими нулями, то делайте это там, где показываете. Очевидно, сохранить ведущие нули в int-поле у вас не выйдет. Либо используйте другой тип поля. В любом случае, default ограничение не является какой-то маской, применимой к вставляемому значению.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание, я нашла решение!!!!

Comment: Если нашли решение, то опубликуйте его ответом. или удалите вопрос вовсе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я нашла вот такой вариант ответа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В необходимое поле указала длину и выбрала `Unsigned, Zerofill`.
Сработал.